# How to fix pylint error "Unnecessary use of a comprehension"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

With python 3.8.6 and pylint 2.4.4 the following code produces a pylint error (or recommendation)

```
R1721: Unnecessary use of a comprehension (unnecessary-comprehension)
```

This is the code:

```
dict1 = {
    "A": "This is A",
    "B": "This is B"
}
bools = [True, False]

dict2 = {key: value for key, value in zip(dict1.keys(), bools)}
```

How can I fix the code to get rid of this R1721 message?

Comment: `dict2 = dict(zip(dict1.keys(), bools))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dict` constructor takes an iterable of key/value pairs, so as the message says, a dict comprehension is unnecessary here.

```py
dict2 = dict(zip(dict1.keys(), bools))
```

Comment: I think you could even do `dict(zip(dict1, bools))`, since iterating over a dict iterates over the keys by default, no?

Comment: @PaulM. Yes; I think it's a matter of style whether you prefer to write `.keys()` to be more explicit. I personally don't.