# Tool to automatically fix pylint "unnecessary-comprehension"?

Tags: python, pylint

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902301/how-to-fix-pylint-error-unnecessary-use-of-a-comprehension) shows pylint reporting `unnecessary-comprehension` on this code:

```
dict1 = {"A": "This is A", "B": "This is B"}
bools = [True, False]

dict2 = {key: value for key, value in zip(dict1.keys(), bools)}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586757/how-do-i-automatically-fix-lint-issues-reported-by-pylint) asks in general if there is an automated tool to fix pylint issues.  It mentions black, autopep8, autoflake8.  None of those fix this.

Is there a tool to apply that would fix this pylint warning?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is not tool to fix that exact example automatically because you need to change the code and produce the same result, which is not easy to automate.

Comment: Autofixing all face the challenge you cite.  What’s probably happening here is that the OP’s issue is not a frequently-occurring and easy fix.